# nginx , tomcat , не тянутся изображения(404)

Tags: nginx, изображения, tomcat, http-status-code-404, кэширование

Доброго времени суток, имеется nginx 1.10, tomcat 8.
Нгинкс смотрит на томкат.В томкате, в задеплоиной папке есть новое изображение Image.png, захожу по урлу, картинку не вижу, зато со старыми изображениями все нормально.
Конф Nginx:

```
upstream upstr {
    server xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080;}
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2:2 keys_zone=one:4000m inactive=10m max_size=50m; 

server {

    listen       7000;

    root /home/folder/media;

    client_max_body_size 10m;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    location /api/images/  {
        alias /home/folder/media/;
        expires 1m;
    }
    location /images/  {
    alias /home/folder/media/;
    expires 1m;
    }
    location /api/*/images/  {
        alias /home/folder/media/;
        expires 1m;
    }

    location /resources/  {
    root /home/folder/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/ROOT/;
    expires 1m;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://upstr;
        proxy_set_header Host coolhost;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_pass_header x-msisdn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Для выделения кода в начале _каждой_ строки должно стоять 4 пробела ;)

Comment: приведите (прямо в вопросе) url, по которому вы обращаетесь, и местоположение файла в файловой системе, который должен отдаваться по этому запросу. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: вопрос уже решен, балансировщик смотрел на доп. ноду которая еще не настроена)), всем спасибо